# empty object in controller from thymeleaf form

Tags: model-view-controller, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table showing testResults using thymeleaf template -

```html
 <tr th:each="testResult,iterationStatus  : ${testResults}">
  <td th:text="${iterationStatus.count}">1</td>
  <td th:text="${testResult.name}">DOMAIN</td>
  <td th:text="${testResult.length}">PROCESS</td>
  <td>
   <form ACTION="#" th:action="@{/deleteName}" th:object="${testResult}" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" th:field="*{name}"/>
       <input type="hidden" th:field="*{length}"/>
       <button type="submit">submit</button>
   </form>
  </td>      
 </tr>
```

name and length are showing fine in the html, but when i submit the form, controller gets name and length as empty values.
What i am doing wrong in assigning the values....

below is controller method that gets invoked -

```
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deleteName")
    public String deleteName(@Valid @ModelAttribute("testResult") TestResult testResult, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(testResult.toString());
        return "/";
    }
```

output once i submit the form -
 
        TestResult [name=, length=, xyz=null]

Comment: Please post the controller code.  At a minimum, post the controller method declaration and annotations.

Comment: added controller details, thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get `th:field` to work inside a `th:object`, like you're doing here.  However, if I stop using `th:field`, and use `th:value` instead, the form submits successfully.

```
<tr th:each="testResult : ${testResults}">
    <td th:text="${testResult.name}">DOMAIN</td>
    <td th:text="${testResult.length}">PROCESS</td>
    <td>
        <form ACTION="#" th:action="@{/deleteName}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" th:value="${testResult.name}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="length" th:value="${testResult.length}"/>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It works although makes me skeptical about using thymeleaf templates. Thanks

Comment: @chappalprasad: I'll spend a few minutes later today digging into why it isn't working with th:field. I wanted to give you a fix as soon as possible, in case your problem was blocking you from getting things done.

Comment: I spend some more time looking though the thymeleaf code.  It appears the th:field code binds differently than th:value does.  th:field requires the th:object you're working with to be directly on the model. In your case, "testResult" is only in your th:each scope. I'm unsure why they work differently, but that's why it doesn't work for you here.

Comment: Thanks  for investigating further. th:value took care of my needs so i am good.